# How can I convert a date coming in as YYYYMMDD into MM/DD/YYYY or MM/D/YYYY depending on its length

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, angular7

I am getting a response back from an API and need to pass that response into another API header in a different format.

From the first api I am getting a date as `YYYYMMDD` and I need to pass it as a header in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Some conditions are, if the day is a single digit (1-9) it should be converted into this format `MM/D/YYYY`.  If the day is a double digit, it should be in this format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

2 examples would be:

- the length for the date is 7, `1999101` should be converted to `10/1/1999`
- the length for the date is 8, `19991020` should be converted to `10/20/1999`

I cannot use moment js.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you hoping to pass it in directly from one into another? Can you add a step that brute force creates strings with substrings? Like `myString[4,5] + "/"` ... etc

Comment: You say YYYYMMDD in the title but you describe YYYYMD which is much more challenging.

Comment: _"if the DD is a single digit (1-9)..."_ - It doesn't make sense

Comment: If the day comes in as a single digit (1-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do this natively without using a library it's pretty trivial also:

```
function convertDate(input) {
    var year = input.substring(0, 4);
    var month = input.substring(4, 6);
    var day = input.substring(6);

    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
```

With that function to get the date you'd run:

```
var date = convertDate("1999101"); // "10/1/1999"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Moment.js library for fast and easy conversion of the data.

Like

```
var date = moment("19991020", "YYYYMMDD");
date.format("MM/DD/YYYY"); // 10/20/1999
```

For further details please check [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/)

Comment: I think OP is looking for `MM/D/YYYY` format due to the single digit requirement. All formats can be found at: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

Comment: Per his description the format should be `MM/D/YYYY` (single digit date).

Comment: I need both formats, correct.  I cannot use another library like moment js.